# Is it possible to use JSON file as backend storage in Code First Entity Framework?

Tags: json, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

First of all I am talking about **WinForms projects** on Win10 and not ASP.NET in case somebody feels inclined to answer for ASP.NET.

Now, I will be using Entity Framework with code-first approach, I have used that in the past a lot with SQL & SQL Lite.

My question is, what if I don't want to use SQL/Lite as **backend** but use **JSON**? I noticed a nice WPF application storing all its relational data in a JSON file but I can't seem to find anything regarding using JSON as my backend RDBMS. It won't be a large database, but it is definitely relational data.

I use Entity Framework, Winforms, .NET and C#. I would like to have something like this:

```
class Top {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public TagInfo MainTag {get;set;}
   public HashSet<TagInfo> TagCatalog {get;set;}
}

class TagInfo {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string TagName {get;set;}
   public Color  TagColor {get;set;}
   public DogInfo Dog {get;set;}
}

class DogInfo {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string DogName {get;set;}
   public Color  DogColor {get;set;}
}
```

What I say is that when I serialize `Top` I don't want the `Top.MainTag` to be serialized as the full `TagInfo` but only its ID because all the tag information is already on the `TagCatalog` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need EF for that.  Just use a JSON serializer to save and load a bunch of objects to a file.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Thanks! Unfortunately, the MS JSON appears to be broken. I can serialize my object but it does not deserialize it (and gives no errors)

Comment: Then post a new question with the class definition and the code to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: If you are MS you might want to take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252221/jsonserializer-silently-fails-to-deserialize-my-object because I think it is a bug. In any case I decided to remove the MS code and use Newtonsoft instead, that one worked well.

Comment: I have been exploring the subject. I have an application that now stores most of its data in a JSON file using Newtonsoft.Json BUT the point of my original question is that my top level class has properties and some of them (MainTag in this example) should not be serialized as a whole TagInfo but only reference it because the TagCatalog will be serialized as whole as part of the TagCatalog property serialization.

Comment: Either change the model to add an IsMainTag property and use that to find the MainTag or do this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm